# Use Inner Select value in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqlxml

I have an SQL query that I am trying to use a subs elects `value` in the outer `where` clause.

```
SELECT   count(A.[processID]) AS total,
         B.[process] AS processName,
         (SELECT   TOP 1 LocationDesc
          FROM     dbo.EmployeeTable_Historical AS D
          WHERE    C.leaver = D.QID
          ORDER BY meta_logDate DESC)
FROM     dbo.attritionDataPrevention AS A
         INNER JOIN
         attritionProcesses AS B
         ON A.[processID] = B.[processID]
         INNER JOIN
         dbo.attritionData AS C
         ON A.[recordID] = C.recordID
WHERE    D.[locationDesc] IN (SELECT location
                              FROM   @table)
         AND YEAR(C.[leaveDate]) = @year
GROUP BY B.[processID]
ORDER BY total DESC
FOR      XML PATH ('type'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

In my main `WHERE` clause, it is saying that it cant BIND `WHERE D.[locationDesc]`. The `S` alias is in a sub query so I'm not too sure how to use its value.

**UPDATE**

Per suggestion, I changed the code to the following:

```
SELECT   count(A.[processID]) AS total,
                         B.[process] AS processName
FROM     dbo.attritionDataPrevention AS A
         INNER JOIN
         attritionProcesses AS B
         ON A.[processID] = B.[processID]
         INNER JOIN 
         dbo.attritionData AS C
         ON A.recordID = C.recordID,
         (
             SELECT TOP 1 D.LocationDesc
             FROM dbo.EmployeeTable_Historical AS D
             WHERE C.leaver = D.QID
             ORDER BY D.[meta_logDate] DESC
         ) AS D
WHERE    D.locationDesc IN (SELECT location FROM @table)
         AND YEAR(C.[leaveDate]) = @year
GROUP BY B.[process]
ORDER BY total DESC
FOR      XML PATH ('type'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

The only issue now is `WHERE C.leaver` wont bind to the inner join.

Comment: Putting subselect statements in the select portion of your query is usually an indication of a poorly formed query.  Move that subselect down into your from statement and alias it, then you can access its fields.

Comment: @paqogomez when I did this, I can no longer access C.leaver that is in the sub select in the `FROM`  statement- not sure why

Comment: Your edit isnt quite what I suggested, this will lead to a cartesian product.  Why do you need it in a subselect at all?  What is it about the result that requires the top 1?

Comment: The historical table contains multiple records for users any time data changes. I order is DESC to get their most recent / current changes and since there can be multiple records per user, I need 1 result

Comment: Instead of just adding a `,`  try `inner join (subselect) d on d.QID = C.leaver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT   count(A.[processID]) Over (Partition by B.[processID]) AS total,
         B.[process] AS processName,
         (SELECT   TOP 1 LocationDesc
          FROM     dbo.EmployeeTable_Historical AS D
          WHERE    C.leaver = D.QID
          AND D.[locationDesc] IN (SELECT location FROM @table)
          ORDER BY meta_logDate DESC)
FROM     dbo.attritionDataPrevention AS A
         INNER JOIN
         attritionProcesses AS B
         ON A.[processID] = B.[processID]
         INNER JOIN
         dbo.attritionData AS C
         ON A.[recordID] = C.recordID
WHERE    YEAR(C.[leaveDate]) = @year
ORDER BY total DESC
FOR      XML PATH ('type'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: The only thing with this is I don't want to group by `leaver` but its forcing me to now that its in the select statement.

Comment: I have made some edits to my answer, you can use partition by clause, if you don't want to group on any other column used in Select statement. 
Also please check if you need to group by ProcessID , while you want to count the ProcessIds .